# Why do KSA and UAE put billions of reserve money into Pakistan's bank but China doesn't?

Tags: china, pakistan, saudi-arabia, united-arab-emirates

Recently, the KSA (Kingdom of Saudi Arabia) agreed to inject $3 billion into Pakistan's state bank. This is the second time KSA is doing so.

In the past, the UAE (United Arab Emirates) also did the same.

We all know that [China is Pakistan's most important ally](https://web.archive.org/web/20110727131107/http://articles.cnn.com/2011-05-17/world/china.pakistan.friend_1_minister-yousuf-raza-gilani-chinese-president-hu-jintao-pakistani-counterpart?_s=PM:WORLD) (also see [here](http://en.people.cn/90001/90776/90883/7384378.html)). Pakistan's PM (Prime Minister) visited China in 2018 to obtain the same facility as the KSA provided with, but, allegedly, China refused.

So, why isn't China doing the same as the KSA/UAE?

Comment: Pakistan and China lately did a lot of business together, but common interest in some trades does not necessary mean an alliance. High level visits are quite common all over the world, they don't imply an alliance as well. So, the assumption this question is based on "We all know ..." is flawed.

Comment: China has invested money in Pakistan, but China only invests where it suits its own interests. Even if countries are close allies, that doesn't mean they'll throw money away without expectation of getting anything in return. Also, as we saw in Afghanistan, China is maybe less worried about regional governments falling, and could even see an opportunity in a bank collapse, but that's pure supposition. Ultimately, China is very secretive and we are unlikely to know its precise motives.

Comment: It's mostly all vendor financing. KSA, UAE, Qatar deliver energy, China delivers industry, infrastructure, electronics, manufactured goods, military equipment, and strategic backup vs arch-rival India. There is also a side trade with Pakistan providing mercenaries that are the backbone of forces in the various ops KSA and UAE have bankrolled, such as in Libya, Syria, Yemen, and perhaps elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

"We all know that China is Pakistan's most important ally."  Do we know that?  Is China actually an ally of Pakistan, or is it just using Pakistan as a tool against India?

Perhaps you've failed to consider that Saudi Arabia and the UAE share an important characteristic - religion - with Pakistan, but not with China.  In fact, China regards this characteristic as a significant threat when it's closer to home.  See for instance recent articles about their treatment of Uyghurs &c.

If we look at matters from this perspective, it makes sense that China would trade with and support Pakistan just enough for it to be useful against India, but not enough to make it powerful enough to become a threat to China, by supporting China's Islamic minority groups.

Comment: So, how to you describe CPEC ?

Comment: *or, is it just using Pakistan as a tool against India?* --- I am totally skeptical. Pakistan established its relation with China in 1962/63 just after the Indo-China War. Pakistan helped China to normalize its relations with the USA and to acquire a seat in the UNSC.  So, this statement of yours has little truth in it.

Comment: I am not going to accept this answer as it doesn't have much substance in it, and is based on false hypothesis.

Comment: *Do we know that? Is China actually an ally of Pakistan* --- Yes. [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China%E2%80%93Pakistan_relations) says that - *The PRC has provided economic, military, and technical assistance to Pakistan, and each country considers the other a close strategic ally.*